# Ubuntu installation alongside Windows 8.1 is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, graphics, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 but now when I open my laptop it says "The system is running in low-graphics mode" and when I press Enter it prompts

> What would you like to do
>
> - run in low graphics mode
> - reconfigure graphics
> - troubleshoot the error
> - exit to console login

Also there is no cursor so I can't select anything.

When I press Esc, black screen appears which asks for my username and password. When I enter the directory changes to my username but after that nothing happens.

Moreover I don't know where my Windows is?

Answer (score 0):

I had HALF of your experience *in the past hour* as the result of installing an accelerated graphics card.  In my case all I had to do to solve the issue was remove the accelerated graphics card, but that's probably not going to work for you.

As to your windows installation, you should have been greeted by a boot manager at boot time, provided you selected "side by side" installations when you installed Ubuntu.  If you opted to use the entire hard disk, then your windows installation has been deleted.  Sorry.

I suggest you boot to whatever medium used to install Ubuntu and once that has loaded, open either [Disk Utility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/) to examine the content of the hard drive and look for any NTFS partitions.  If you have any, then your windows has survived and all you need to do is use the [boot repair tool](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) to restore the windows boot option.